# Editing Salesforce Visualforce pages in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, salesforce

I'm using the Eclipse IDE with the Force.com plugin for editing Salesforce.com visual force pages. The problem I'm having is that I can't actually edit the page. Whether it's a newly created page or not. I right click on the project within Eclipse, clicked new visual force page and the page loads. I can actually edit anything though.

Any ideas? Do I need an additional web plugin or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are no additional plugins required. You may have an issue with your Eclipse install.

Easiest way to confirm is to download Eclipse again. I'd do the plain Java package. Install into a new location on your disk, then install the Force.com plugin.

Comment: I also prefer the plugin compared to the full Force.com IDE. Make sure to install it on your main hard drive (C:) as opposed to in the Program Files folder (I've found a few issues with installing plugins when adding it to Program Files).